# How to make the "typing screen" bigger in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I make this window bigger in VS Code?

I cant see the continued of the methods

[image: vscode window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto the **View** menu, then **Appearance** and **Zoom In** (Ctrl++). This will make the quick suggestions window bigger.

Afterwards, in the Settings.json you can reduce the "editor.fontSize" again until it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Full screen mode along with other options.

Press *Ctrl+K* and then *Z* to open editor in full screen without explorer and terminal, etc.

And you can use *Ctrl+B* to show/hide side bar and *Ctrl+J* to show terminal and console panel.